# Add and subtract simultaneously in one formula

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I have 3 columns in my details section:

1. s.no
2. balance
3. type

I want my formula field total to subtract the value if the type is *debit* and add the value when it is *credit*. The logic would look like this in C++. How can I rewrite this in Crystal syntax?

```
if(type=="credit")    
    total = total+balance    
else if((type=="credit")   
    total = total-balance;
```

Comment: How is the data coming into crystal?

Comment: @Matt by sql server

Comment: total is a variable? which one of this came from your query?if(type=="credit)    
total = total+balance    
else if((type=="credit)   
total = total-balance;

Comment: are you using odbc connection?

Comment: @HimanshuGoel just write it in SQL and bring in the total

Comment: @reds no I wrote that code because I wanted to show the function I want it to perform. All the data comes from a table in sql server I want to make a formula field total to know the total of balance coloumn. The total field should add itself when type coloum is credit and subtract itself when is debit

Comment: Do you have a constructed query already? i guess so

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for crystal report formula

```
If {type} = "credit" Then
{total} := {total} + {balance}
Else If {type} = "debit" Then
{total} := {total} - {balance}
```

Alternately you can write case statement in `sql query` to get `updated_total`

```
SELECT type, total,balance.....,  
   CASE   
      WHEN type ="credit" THEN (total + balance)   
      WHEN type ="debit"  THEN  (total - balance)  
   END  as updated_total 
FROM Datatable ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a formula field called `UpdatedTotal` and input the following code:

```
If {type} = "debit" Then
    {total} - {balance}
Else If {type} = "credit" Then
    {total} + {balance}
```

Then just drop the formula field into the report wherever you want it to display.

In Crystal it's not necessary to assign the updated total value: This new field automatically displays the updated total and can be used in other calculations by referencing `{@UpdatedTotal}` by name.